# Is there an opposite for Guiding Ariadne?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Most pendulum monsters have an opposite. For example [Dragonpulse Magician](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonpulse_Magician), [Dragonpit Magician](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonpit_Magician).  One is pendulum value 1 the other 8. My question is, is there an opposite for [Guiding Ariadne](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Guiding_Ariadne)? Something like:

> Monster effect, Level 5 or 7, Pendulum level 6 or 8, Type Fairy, Attribute Light, Attack _____, Defense _____
>
> Pendulum Effect: Each time you activate a counter trap card your opponent takes 500 damage.
>
> Monster Effect: Each time you activate a counter trap card you gain 500 life points.

Basically a card that ties with the pendulum effect of Guiding Ariadne but is higher pendulum level.

Comment: [A search of Yu-Gi-Oh's database](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&rp=10&mode=&sort=1&keyword=&stype=1&ctype=&attr=11&species=17&othercon=2&starfr=&starto=&level5=on&level7=on&pscalefr=&pscaleto=&Pscale6=on&Pscale8=on&linkmarkerfr=&linkmarkerto=&link_m=2&atkfr=&atkto=&deffr=&defto=) indicates that the only card that fulfills your first line of requirements is Rain Bozu.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a card to your exact specifics.
There are some online tools though that might help you find cards relevant to your needs. You can use sites like:
https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action
https://www.duelingbook.com

With these you can filter cards to find only pendulums with certain scales/types/attributes and search for keywords in the name and description (for example, you could look for the word damage to look for cards with a burn effect)